# Routing within an Angular function

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase

I have a login function here that allows a user to login and will navigate to a certain component (changepw) based on whether a piece of firebase information (active flag) is true or false. Even though I read read the data fine, when it is false, I am not getting a redirection with this code. change pw and /changepw have been tried. Help!

```
  login(email: string, password: string): void {
    
      this.firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)


      .then(value => {

        var userId = value.user.uid;
        this.db.database.ref(('users/' + userId)).get().then(value => {
          var userInfo = value.toJSON();
          console.log(userInfo['active'])

          if ( userInfo == false ) {
            this.router.navigate(['changepw']);
          } else {
            this.router.navigate(['']);
          }

        })
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('Something went wrong:', err.message);
        alert(err.message);
      });
    }
```

Comment: Could you post your routing file to see if there may be an issue there?

Answer (score 0):

if you have something like this in app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes : Routes = [
{path:"changepw",component abcComponent}
]
```

then you should add front slash in navigate

```
this.router.navigate(['/changepw']);
```

share Routes in appRouting module also share if you have any error in console

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you have tried this approach or not

```
this.router.navigate(['/', 'changepw']);
```

What this does is, after the `/` it will append the changepw route.

Since `this.router.navigate([]);` is an array, you need to split the path if it has a `/` or something lke that .